# Why suddenly can't find module?

Tags: haskell

I have two files in the same folder, `Eval.hs` and `Data.hs`, module in `Eval.hs` imports module `TI.Data` in `Data.hs`, when I try to load `Eval.hs` in the interactive (in emacs haskell mode: `Ctrl-c, Ctrl l`), it said it can't find the module defined in `Data.hs`, but it loaded successfully before, why suddenly it can't??
btw, I noticed that the first time I execute `Ctrl-c, Ctrl l`, the interative window:

```
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :cd ~/.cabal/                                                          
Prelude> :load "../hs/TI/Eval.hs"                                               

../hs/TI/Eval.hs:2:7:                                                           
    Could not find module `TI.Data':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sometimes have this same problem with haskell-mode on Emacs. My workaround is to

```
Prelude> :cd ~/hs/TI
Prelude> :load "Eval.hs"
```

Now when you want to reload the module you have to use

```
Prelude> :r
```

instead of Ctrl-C, Ctrl-l.

If someone knows a better way, please let me know.

-deech

Comment: I stepped into this problem now and after some fiddling I believe that the problem has to do with haskell-mode having some cabal sensitivity. If there is a cabal file in a parent directory when loading the source file into a buffer ghci will start from there until the source file buffer is reloaded. So either removing the cabal file or adding some declaration that the module that you are trying to load is part of the cabal module should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Prelude> :cd ~/hs
Prelude> :load "TI/Eval.hs"
```

If the modules are actually like `Subdirectory.Contains.A` then the working directory needs to be the directory `Subdirectory`.

Comment: Since the point at which it worked have you compiled either of the modules to `.o`?  Are these part of a cabal package?

Comment: the modules are not part of the cabal package.... should I compile the two modules to .o again?

Comment: Thanks Vivian! It works, after reading your edit. The reason is that whenever I use Ctrl-c, Ctrl-l, the interative automatically execute the `Prelude> :cd ~/.cabal/` to change my correct directory!!!

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
(inferior-haskell-find-project-root nil)
```

to your custom set variables.  It will no longer :cd.

a much better solution would be finding out why the function in `inf-haskell.el` doesn't quite work

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
:set -isrc -imyothersrcdir
```

To add any source directories. You can put this line in a .ghci file in the directory from which you run GHCi.

Alternatively just use cabal repl which does this for you based on your cabal file.